# Retrieve Google Delegated Contacts

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get the delegated contacts from another user of Google.

I managed to get the contacts and  groups from a user.

However, I am not able to get the contacts delegated to me by another user with the API.

I need help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Contact delegation is not available through the API. The only way to access the delegated user contacts is by using [OAuth2 domain wide delegation](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/11/domain-wide-delegation-of-authority-and.html) with a super admin user.

See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/ZVxCtoIBmnY